# node c++ addon / v8 / custom dependency

Tags: c++, node.js, linker, v8, node.js-addon

I am trying to build a node c++ addon on ubuntu using code::blocks. I have build a addon.node shared library that depends on another shared library dep.so . When creating my basid js file with

```
var addon = require(./addon.node);
```

it gives

```
Error: dep.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Error (native)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (module.js:386:17)
   at repl:1:13
   at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:130:27)
   at bound (domain.js:254:14)
   at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
   at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
```

My dep.so file is included while building addon.node and exists in the same build directory as addon.node

running ld addon.node it gives (among other things)

```
ld: warning: dep.so, needed by addon.node, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
addon.node: undefined reference to `v8::ObjectTemplate::SetInternalFieldCount(int)'
```

so, it seems I have two problems:
1) it can't find my own created dep.so library
2) it can't find v8 library (I guess this needs to be build somehow)

Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 1):

[nbind](https://github.com/charto/nbind#readme) makes it easy in general to write Node.js bindings for libraries and [libui-node](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node) is a practical example of using it, to create a cross-platform native UI. Its [`binding.gyp`](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node/blob/master/binding.gyp) file shows how to successfully link with a library called `libui` placed in the root directory of the module (not the build directory).

On Windows:

```
"libraries": [
    "<(module_root_dir)/libui.lib"
]
```

Linux:

```
'ldflags': [
    '-Wl,-rpath,<(module_root_dir)',
],
"libraries": [
    "<(module_root_dir)/libui.so"
]
```

OS X:

```
"xcode_settings": {
    "OTHER_LDFLAGS": [
        "-L<(module_root_dir)",
        "-lui",
        "-rpath",
        "<(module_root_dir)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is correct answer, the key thing here is to specify *-rpath* and *libraries* togather